# Different output from stored procedure in SSMS and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I created a stored procedure to include a new user for my system. Parameters are: Name, Mail and Password (all `varchar`). The stored procedure first checks if the mail is already in the database. If not, then the information in added to the table. At the end, the output is a table with the user data.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[user_new]
    (@name VARCHAR(50), 
     @mail VARCHAR(50),
     @password VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN           
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @exist INT

    SELECT @exist = COUNT([id]) 
    FROM [dbo].[User] 
    WHERE [mail] = @mail

    IF @exist = 0
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] ([name], [mail], [password]) 
        VALUES (@name, @mail, @password)

    SELECT 
        @exist AS [exist], [id], [name], [mail] 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[User] 
    WHERE 
        [mail] = @mail
END
GO
```

When I execute the stored procedure in SSMS, everything works fine: when I insert a new mail, field `[exist]` returns 0. When I insert a mail that already exist, field `[exist]` returns 1. So far, so good.

When I execute the stored procedure from my .NET application (which has a lot of other calls that are working fine), the error happen: no matter if I try to add a new or an existing mail, `[exist]` **always** returns 1. I tried to change the logic several times, but I always get the wrong result.

Here is the .NET code:

```
Public Function api_v2_player_new(<FromBody> s As User) As Object
    Dim arrParameters(,) As String = {{"@name", s.Name}, {"@mail", s.Mail}, {"@password", s.Password}}
    Dim dtc As Data.DataTableCollection = SQL.Execute("dbo.user_new", arrParameters)
    Return SQL.toJson(dtc(0))
End Function

Public Class SQL
    Public Shared Function runStoredProcedure(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As Data.DataTableCollection
        Dim spName As String = cmd.CommandText.ToString
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
        Dim cs As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("csKickerliga").ConnectionString
        Dim connection As SqlConnection = Nothing
        connection = New SqlConnection(cs)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        cmd.Connection = connection
        connection.Open()
        Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        adp.Fill(ds, spName)
        Return ds.Tables
        connection.Close()
    End Function

    Shared Function Execute(spName As String, arrParameters(,) As String) As Data.DataTableCollection
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(spName)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        With cmd.Parameters
            For i = 0 To (arrParameters.Length / 2) - 1
                .AddWithValue(arrParameters(i, 0), arrParameters(i, 1))
            Next
        End With
        Dim dtc = runStoredProcedure(cmd)
        Return dtc
    End Function

    Shared Function toJson(dt As DataTable) As List(Of Object)
        Dim oList As New List(Of Object)
        Dim o As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Dim data As Object

        For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
            o = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            For Each c As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                If IsNumeric(r(c.ColumnName)) Then
                    If Not r(c.ColumnName).ToString.Contains(".") Then
                        data = CInt(r(c.ColumnName))
                    Else
                        data = r(c.ColumnName).ToString
                    End If
                Else
                    data = r(c.ColumnName).ToString
                End If
                o.Add(c.ColumnName, data)
            Next
            oList.Add(o)
        Next
        Return oList
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Show us how you call the proc from the .Net app

Comment: There is no `FROM` in your `Select`...  `SELECT @exist AS [exist], [id], [name], [mail] WHERE [mail]=@mail`

Comment: If Sp working fine in SSMS then Check your connection string(server name, database name) and Sp name that u passed at the time of calling from asp, and if they are fine then check parameters that r u passing.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Post corrected. The SP is correct in my database. Copy/paste issue... :-)

Comment: @TabAlleman [explanation from post] no matter if I try to add a new or an existing mail, [exist] always returns 1. I tried to change the logic several times, but I always get the wrong result.

Comment: Are you sure the parameters are what you expect? Maybe your .NET call pass an empty string or something. We would also need to see that part of the code.

Comment: @AmitYadav Connection String is not the problem, I got result, but a wrong result. I also have a lot of other Store Procedures working fine

Comment: @the_lotus yes, because the INSERT command works fine.

Comment: @DaniloKörber i am not saying connection string is wrong, i want to say that may you have two servers one is prod and another is testing so my concern is that you are changing in test and making connection from prod or vice versa.

Comment: @AmitYadav got it, but I have only one server for this application, so it's not the case. :-)

Comment: @the_lotus my output is a table (SELECT) and I get the expected data, **except** for this one  `exist` field.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin I added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The code was executing the stored procedure twice:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
adp.Fill(ds, spName)
```

Therefore on the recond run the record already existed because it was created on the first run. I removed one of the lines and now it's working!